# how to import csv file in mysql database limiting the number of rows?

Tags: sql, csv

I have a csv file with 45,00,000 rows and i need a way to limit the number of rows to be imported in the database say 1,00,000 rows.How can I import the limited number of rows in the mysql database?

Comment: Well, what did you try so far that didn't work? People here (myself included) like to see that you've put some work into a problem before asking, not just looking for someone to do your homework.

Comment: strange number of rows on that csv file...

Comment: On which OS is this? Can you partition off part of the file? And I think you need to develop your question more by editing your OP and adding more informatino.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use PhpMyAdmin - this has an option to break up your CSV file into multiple requests when doing the import. Check out this article: http://www.group3solutions.com/blog/tips-on-phpmyadmin-csv-importing/

Also - you could try this application: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/ . It worked for me before.